# String is not a function-Filesaver.js

Tags: javascript, html, file, file-io

I am using filesaver.js and I have the following js code

```
function download(){
            //ejectCss();

        var t="snnsnsns\n";
        t+="aslhgakgskasgkgsakgas[]\n\n\n\"";
        var blob = new Blob([t], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
saveAs(blob, "sliders-ui-custom-classes.css");


    }
```

To trigger that function I am using this:

```
<a   class="btn btn-warning btn-block container" onclick="download()">Download user-created classes</a>
```

But i get an error saying"String is not a function".Any ideas?
Also this is not working

```
<a   class="btn btn-warning btn-block container" onclick="download();">Download user-created classes</a>
```

Comment: put semi-colon in anchor tag after download()

Comment: better yet, abstract event handling from your html

Comment: Where is `saveAs` defined?

Comment: saveAs is from filesaver.js plugin.This piece of code is copied from an other script i made and in the other script it is working but not in my new one

Comment: Is the error occurring in the 3rd party script or the code above?

Comment: The error occurs in that part of code

Comment: can you change the function name "download" to some other, and test it? Because I guess download is a html attribute.

Comment: That did the trick.I used an other a tag with download attribute which caused the problem